# Handle records in Parallel Mode

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I was asked to run a heavy update after DB conversion, for a given list of Orders ID's ,

I need to go over the list and handle each ID.

For example:

--Customer Table:

create table CustOrders 
( ID int , 
  CustFName varchar(10), 
 CustLname varchar(10),
 Primary key(ID)
)

For each id in the list, a stored procedure will update the record.

My first thought was to:

1. Create stored procedure which accepts list of id's (with table value parameter) .
2. For each id , do my stuff

But then I’ve realized it will take too much time and there for I came up with an idea

And try and run in a parallel mode, for example:

Try to run several stored procedure where each stored procedure handles different bulk of ID's ,

Divided by Mod operator for example .

This is the reason I have decided to publish the question, maybe you have a better idea how to write procedure which can run in parallel mode.

Comment: Update it how? If you give more details someone can probably show you how to do this without doing it one by one (which is certainly going to be more expensive than updating them all at once, something SQL Server is very good at, or at least in batches of, say, 10000 rows at a time). Whenever you are working in SQL Server and think "I need to do x one row at a time" step back and think again, because in most cases that is the wrong way to do it.

Comment: Also whose requirement is it that these updates be run in parallel? Is there some perception that two updates to the same page can happen at the same time? While it is possible to split up the updates into different batches based on the clustered index, this only helps if there are also no clustered indexes on the table, and is still going to be a pain in the butt to coordinate. Why not tell us how you're updating, get suggestions for doing it the most efficient way, and *then* see if there is a performance issue. Instead of telling us you need to solve performance by parallelizing it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a partitioned table?  If not running parallel updates is probably not going to help.  It is still a single set of write heads at the other end.